# Регулярное выражение для поиска чисел с процентами возвращает только первое вхождение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть следующая строка: `string 1,2,100%,50%` и мне надо найти числа с процентами.

Пробовал так: `x = re.search("\d+%","string 1,2,100%,50%")`, но он находит только одно (`100%`).

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Использовать [findall](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
import re
text = 'string 1,2,100%,50%'
print(re.findall("\d+%", text))
# ['100%', '50%']
```

Вариант без регулярки:

```
text = 'string 1,2,100%,50%'
print([x for x in text.split()[1].split(',') if x.endswith('%')])  # ['100%', '50%']

# Используя filter
items = list(filter(lambda x: x.endswith('%'), text.split()[1].split(',')))
print(items)   # ['100%', '50%']

text = 'string 1%,2,100%,50%'
print([x for x in text.split()[1].split(',') if x.endswith('%')])  # ['1%', '100%', '50%']
```

Comment: Если текст будет `'string 1%,2,100%,50%'`, то вариант без регулярки неправильно сработает.

Comment: @insolor, угу, но лучше ориентироваться на текущие данные, можно вообще предусмотреть все ситуации и выйдет в итоге лексический парсер :) а так будет что-то вроде: `[x for x in text.split()[1].split(',') if x.endswith('%')]`